# Error :cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Tags: python, python-requests, python-3.8

Hy am using Python RegEx to show all internet wirless profiles connected to a computer.There is error `(TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object)` in my Second last line pls anyone help to identifi my mistake.Thanks

**My Program**

```
import subprocess,re
command = "netsh wlan show profile"
output = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)  
network_names = re.search("(Profile\s*:\s)(.*)", output)  
print(network_names.group(0))
```

.....................................................

**ERROR**

```
line 8, in <module>


 return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)


TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

Comment: You could try str(output) in your re.search or output.decode('utf-8') maybe?

Comment: `output = output.decode()` ? `subprocess` return `bytes` and you have to manually convert to `string`/`unicode` (using default `'utf-8'` or  other encoding - ie. `decode('latin1')` - if system uses different encoding then `utf-8`)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Python 3 distinguishes "[bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#binary-sequence-types-bytes-bytearray-memoryview)" and "[string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str)" types; this is especially important for Unicode strings, where each character may be more than one byte, depending on the character and the encoding.

Regular expressions can work on either, but it has to be consistent — searching for bytes within bytes, or strings within strings.

Depending on what you need, there are two solutions:

- Decode the `output` variable before searching in it; for instance, with: `output_text = output.decode('utf-8')`

  This depends on the encoding that you are using; UTF-8 is the most common these days.

  The matched group will be a string.
- Search with bytes by adding a `b` prefix to the regular expression. A regular expression should also use the `r` prefix, so it becomes: `re.search(br"(Profile\s*:\s)(.*)", output)`

  The matched group will be a bytes object.

Comment: Decoding the output variable before searching worked for me..

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation for `Popen.stdout`:

> If the stdout argument was PIPE, this attribute is a readable stream
>   object as returned by open(). Reading from the stream provides output
>   from the child process. **If the encoding or errors arguments were
>   specified or the universal_newlines argument was True, the stream is a
>   text stream, otherwise it is a byte stream**. If the stdout argument was
>   not PIPE, this attribute is None.

So without setting these options you get a byte stream.

`subprocess.check_output` supports an `encoding` keyword argument. Set this to `'utf8'` and you will get a text stream:

```py
output = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True, encoding='utf8')
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same code on my computer with python 2.7. 
Works perfect.

Output is a str object on my side.

I think you can add a line after this code "output = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)", the line is print(type(output)).

You may see the real data type, if it's not str, try to use output = str(output) to convert it to str

Comment: Python 2 treats `bytes` as `string` but Python 3 doesn't treast `bytes` as `string`

Comment: So I said use str method to convert to str

Comment: The downside of using `output = str(output)` is that (a) it'll add `b'` and `'` marks around the text, and (b) it won't work well for accented characters, emoji, etc.

For instance, instead of **café** it'll print out **b'caf\xc3\xa9'**

Using the `.decode()` method will treat all these characters correctly.