# Python TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Tags: python-3.x, linux, pattern-matching, matcher, hexdump

I tried to use python script to find a repeated copies of the configuration section within the binary dump file, using pattern and magic header.The config section always starts with 202 '0xff' bytes followed by 4 bytes '\x00\x00\x23\x27'. The script should identify different copies of config section within the  partition and print the addresses where they start.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import re
import mmap
import sys

magic = '\xff' * 202
pattern = magic + '\x00\x00\x23\x27'

fh = open(sys.argv[1], "r+b")
mf = mmap.mmap(fh.fileno(), 0)
mf.seek(0)
fh.seek(0)
for occurence in re.finditer(pattern, mf):
    print(occurence.start())
mf.close()
fh.close()
```

I got the error:

```
$ ./matcher.py dump.bin
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/eviecomp/BC2UTILS/dump_previous_profile/./matcher.py", line 13, in <module>
    for occurence in re.finditer(pattern, mf):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/re.py", line 248, in finditer
    return _compile(pattern, flags).finditer(string)
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

Please advice how to fix script.

Comment: `mf` is a bytes-like object. `re.finditer` needs a string as its second argument.

Comment: What happens if you replace `mf` in `re.finditer(...)` with `mf.decode()`? See here for why you may want to do that: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode

Comment: @jjramsey  tried, got another error: `./matcher2.py dump.bin
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/eviecomp/BC2UTILS/dump_previous_profile/./matcher2.py", line 13, in <module>
    for occurence in re.finditer(pattern, mf.decode()):
AttributeError: 'mmap.mmap' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Comment: What about trying `mf[:].decode()` instead?

Comment: `./matcher2.py dump.bin
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/eviecomp/BC2UTILS/dump_previous_profile/./matcher2.py", line 13, in <module>
    for occurence in re.finditer(pattern, mf[:].decode()):
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte`

Comment: You're mixing bytes with strings. This should answer your question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61720217/error-cannot-use-a-string-pattern-on-a-bytes-like-object

Comment: So, in general, I should search for _bytes within bytes_, or _strings within strings_. Since I'm working with raw dump file in a binary format,  I want search for bytes. How to fix this in the script?

Answer (score 0):

So I find the answer myself: I have to use `b''` literals:

```
magic = b'\xff' * 202
pattern = magic + b'\x00\x00\x23\x27'
```

so the script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import re
import mmap
import sys

magic = b'\xff' * 202
pattern = magic + b'\x00\x00\x23\x27'

fh = open(sys.argv[1], "r+b")
mf = mmap.mmap(fh.fileno(), 0)
mf.seek(0)
fh.seek(0)
for occurence in re.finditer(pattern, mf):
    print(occurence.start())
mf.close()
fh.close()
```